# How to hide or keep away /node

Tags: nodes, uri

I want to avoid the URL pointing to a node on my site contains the "node" part (e.g. http://example.com/node/1). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Path module for URL aliases. (It is a Drupal core module.)

Once the module is enabled, you can edit a node, and set a path alias for the node. Now, you can access your node through the path alias you just created.
Drupal will use the path alias you set as URL for the node, except for sub-paths (e.g. node/1/edit).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. It's suitable for your work.

The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Path module for the URL alias, and for every pages use a path alias.